# How to set file permissions on apache for windows

Tags: apache, windows-7, file-permissions

I cannot find any documentation that answers this.  How do I set file permissions on a windows machine running apache so that a file/folder can only be accessed by an admin/user and not the general public I want my machine to serve?  It seems like if admin/system user has permission to access a file, then when request is made that apache is handling, apache would be running on behalf of admin/system and get permissions.  I want to be able run a script which is not reachable to the public in a folder which is available to the public.